# I am confused with Enumerations

Tags: java, enumeration, java-5

If enums are used from jdk1.5 onwards , what was the use of java.util.Enumeration interface
before jdk1.5 ? Can anybody help me explore this with an example please ?

Answer (score 7):

[`Enumeration`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html) is an early Java class essentially replaced by [`Iterator`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html). it is used for iteration of certain largely outdated collections.

[Enums](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html) are Java's version of typesafe enums in the C/C++ sense. They represent a finite and fixed set of values that are canonical but can also have behaviour. They stem from the pattern established by Joshua Bloch in [*Effective Java*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201310058).

In other words, they're not related.

Answer (score 4):

[`Enum`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html) and [`java.util.Enumeration`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html) are unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

java.util.Enumeration was the precursor to java.util.Iterator which was introduced in Java 1.2. Below is an example from the Javadoc of an Enumeration being used to iterate through a  Vector

```
for (Enumeration<E> e = v.elements(); e.hasMoreElements();)
   System.out.println(e.nextElement());
```

It has nothing to do with Java 5 enums.